# Initialize Array in constructor and pass into map in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a model in angular and passing that into map function in service. I have one array in that model. When I pass that its showing **undefined** and except that array rest of the values are coming well. I think I am doing wrong in initializing and calling array. Can any tell me how to do it.

**abc.ts**

```
export class ABC {
    date: Date;
    time: string;
    abc_Info: {
        item: string,
        quantity: number,
        a: number
    } []
    constructor(date: Date, time: string, abc_Info: []) {
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.abc_Info = abc_Info;
    }
}
```

**abc.service**

```
import { ABC} from './models/abc';
getABC(start ? : moment.Moment, end ? : moment.Moment): Observable < ABC[] > {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (start) {
        params = params.append('start', start.toISOString());
    }
    if (end) {
        params = params.append('end', end.toISOString());
    }
    return this.baseService.getParams('/api/abc/getAll', params)
        .pipe(
            map(res => res as Object[] || []),
            map(bolus => bolus.map(k => new Bolus(
                    new Date(k['date']), //Value passing and coming well
                    k['time'], //Value passing and coming well
                    k['abc_Info'] //calling array here, showing undefined when i run
      ))))
}
```

**Response In Back end, This is what I am getting into front end**

```
[
  {
    "date": "2019-01-18T18:30:00.000Z",
    "time": "2019-01-19T04:52:00.389Z",
    "abc_Info": [
      {
        "_id": "5c42acf9a0048b2a683be22a",
        "item": "Idly",
        "quantity": 15,
        "a": 30
      },
      {
        "_id": "5c42acf9a0048b2a683be229",
        "item": "Sandwitch",
        "quantity": 10,
        "a": 25
      },
      {
        "_id": "5c42acf9a0048b2a683be228",
        "item": "Sandwitch",
        "quantity": 20,
        "a": 25
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You have a couple typos in your class: missing a semicolon after the `[ ]` in the type declaration for `abc_Info`, and the type of `abc_Info` in the constructor should be `any[ ]`, or `{ item: string, quantity: number, a: number } [ ]` if you want to be more precise. That aside, can you verify that `res` is correctly formatted?

Comment: I have edited my response. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

There several places you are using the `get()` weirdly, actually you should try to use more of the **Type**Script.

If the response is already `json` then you can use

```
this.http.get<ABC[]>(req);
```

If the response is `text` format then perhaps you can directly use

```
this.http.get<string>(req).pipe(map(s => JSON.parse(s)));
// get the typed array directly
```

Via this basic trick we can directly get the data and present it with

```
<div *ngFor="let c of _ret">
  <h3>{{ c.time }}</h3>
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let info of c.abc_Info">{{ info["item"] }} : {{ info["quantity"] }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can check the [online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oy9pxq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) in which I am using [`interceptor`](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) to mock the server response.