# Calling array in map function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have initialized and declared a model. I am calling that model's element in map function. I have two fields and one array in that model. When I pass the model in map function. I can able to get values for the two fields but my array showing undefined. It seems like my format for array in map is wrong. Can any one help me out.

**abc.ts**

```
export class ABC {
date: Date;
time: string;
ABC_Info: any[];

constructor(date: Date, time: string, ABC_Info: {
    item: string,
    quantity: number,
    a: number
} []) {
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.ABC_Info = ABC_Info;
  }
}
```

**abc.service**

```
import { ABC} from './models/abc';

getABC(start ? : moment.Moment, end ? : moment.Moment): Observable < ABC[] > {
let params = new HttpParams();

if (start) {
    params = params.append('start', start.toISOString());
}

if (end) {
    params = params.append('end', end.toISOString());
}
return this.baseService.getParams('/api/abc/getAll', params)
    .pipe(
        map(res => res as Object[] || []),
        map(abc => abc.map(k => new ABC(
            new Date(k['date']), // I can get values for this, when I GET
            k['time'], //  I can get values for this, when I GET
            k['ABC_Info'] //I am getting undefined for this, when I GET
        )))
    )
 }
```

Comment: Already answered at your first question and please do not post the same question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54264913/2361308